# sequence generated primary keys don't seem to work well with select statements

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, foreign-keys

**sequence generated primary keys don't seem to work well with select statements**

I'm trying to create a transport database. I've already done it in Access and MySQL. Now I'm doing it in
Oracle and I'm totally new to using it. I ran into trouble with a sequence generated field. Or at least I think so. You'll get onboard when 
you read the entire thing.

Here's the code for my driverRecords table:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSPORT_SCHEMA.driverRecords
(
    driverReg varchar2(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    driverIDNumber varchar2(10) UNIQUE,
    surname varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
    otherNames varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    address varchar2(20),
    email varchar2(320) NOT NULL,
    DOB date NOT NULL,
    employmentDate date NOT NULL
);
```

Here's the code for drivingLicences table:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSPORT_SCHEMA.drivingLicences
(
    licenceID varchar2(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    vehicleClass varchar2(15),
    issueDate date,
    expiryDate date,
    driverReg varchar2(15) UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_driverReg FOREIGN KEY(driverReg) REFERENCES driverRecords(driverReg),
    CONSTRAINT Chk_vehicleClass CHECK(vehicleClass IN('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'))
);
```

So I was trying to insert records into drivingLicences. driverReg in drivingLicences is a child key to driverReg in driverRecords. The idea 
is that no driver should exist in the drivingLicences table if their records don't exist in the driverRecords table

Here's the code I was using to do the insertion;

```
insert into drivingLicences VALUES('123456', 'D', '12-12-2019','12-12-2020', 'DRV/1003/2020');
```

And here's the error that was being returned:

*`ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TRANSPORT_SCHEMA.FK_DRIVERREG) violated - parent key not found`*

Now I totally undertand that the error is caused by violation of an integrity constraint... But the problem is... I actually have a driver with the
registration number *`DRV/1003/2020`* in my records

My driver registration numbers are generated by this sequence and trigger:

Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE driverNumberSequence
    START WITH 1000
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NOCACHE
    NOCYCLE;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER regNumberGenerator BEFORE 
INSERT ON driverRecords
FOR EACH ROW

    DECLARE
        prefix char(3) := 'DRV';
        driverNumber char(4);
        postfix char(4);
        generatedDriverNumber char(15);

    BEGIN
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') INTO postfix FROM sys.dual;
        SELECT TO_CHAR(driverNumberSequence.nextval) INTO driverNumber FROM dual;
        generatedDriverNumber:= prefix || '/' || driverNumber || '/' || postfix;
        SELECT TO_CHAR(generatedDriverNumber) INTO :NEW.driverReg FROM dual;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Driver Reg Number generated:' || generatedDriverNumber);
    END;
```

I tried to do two select statements to firgure out what the problem was:

1)`SELECT * FROM DRIVERRECORDS where DRIVERREG = 'DRV/1001/2020';`

This one returns 0 rows

2)`SELECT * FROM DRIVERRECORDS where DRIVERREG LIKE 'DRV/1001/2020%';`

This one actually returned a result

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. But I think it has to do with the way my driverReg info is saved. Any assistance will be appreciated

If it helps, here are all the driver registion numbers I have saved:

```
SELECT driverReg FROM driverRecords;

*DRV/1001/2020
DRV/1002/2020
DRV/1003/2020
DRV/1004/2020
DRV/1005/2020*
```

In a nutshell, I need to know why:

a) the select statement works with `LIKE '%'` and not with `= ''`

b) I can't do the insertion even when I'm not violating integrity constraints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`generatedDriverNumber` in your trigger is defined as `char(15)` - a **fixed length** character field with a length of 15. Since you fill it with a much shorter value, it pads it up to the full length of 15. This explains why querying with a `like` on the begining of the value worked, but not with a `=`.

To make a long story short, change the definition to `varchar2` and you should be OK:

```
generatedDriverNumber varchar2(15);
```

Comment: Also, no need to do "select ... into" statements in your trigger. Just assign the value of the variables directly:

postfix := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY');

driverNumber := TO_CHAR(driverNumberSequence.nextval);

NEW.driverReg := prefix || '/' || driverNumber || '/' || postfix;